# Is it possible in Python to decorate a method in class using method in instance

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to wrap a function when defining the class, use method in this class's instance

Below is a code that works

```
class A(object):   
    def __init__(self):    
        pass       

    @self_decorator 
    def to_be_decorated(self):
        pass       

def self_decorator(fn):    
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(fn)     
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]     
        return self.app.route('/twip')(fn(*args, **kwargs))

    return wrapper
```

What I actually tries to get:

```
class A(object):   
    def __init__(self):    
        self.app = APP()    

    @self.app.wrapper_function # which apparently doesn't work
    def to_be_decorated(self):
        pass
```

So, is it possible for my way of decorating to work?

Answer (score 2):

At the class definition there's no self as the class do not exists yet and cannot be instantiated.

You can use

```
class A(object):
    app = APP()

    @app.wrapper_function
    def to_be_decorated(self):
        pass
```

But that would be a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is just a function that gets called at the time of definition.

When you write this:

```
@self.app.wrapper_function # which apparently doesn't work
def to_be_decorated(self):
    pass
```

it's roughly the same as writing this:

```
def to_be_decorated(self):
    pass
to_be_decorated = self.app.wrapper_function(to_be_decorated)
```

Once you see it that way, it's obvious why this doesn't work, and couldn't possibly work.

First, `A`'s class definition doesn't have a self variable, nor does `A` have a member `app` that could be accessed even if it did. Instead, each instance of `A` will have its own unique `self.app`.

And even if you wish the interpreter could just "do what I mean", if you think about it, that can't mean anything. You want to call "the" `self.app.wrapper_function` method, but there is no such thing. Unless you read through all of the relevant code everywhere the method could be defined or redefined, there's absolutely no guarantee that the `self.app.wrapper_function` from different instances of `A` will even have the same underlying `func_code`. But, even if they did, `self.app.wrapper_function` is a bound method—a method bound together with the object it's called on—so they're still all different from each other.

There are plenty of ways around this, but they're all going to be the same trick: Use some kind of indirection to get a function which isn't a member of `self.app` or `self`, and references `self.app` at call time. This is basically what your `self_decorator` does, and it's unavoidable.